# GCC macro to print all function arguments

Tags: c++, c, gcc, macros, profiling

I need some macro or other way to print current function and its arguments. For the function name it is easy, as we can use e.g. `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`. Is there some macro that holds function arguments? Or can you use `va_list` and `va_start` for non-variadic functions?

Something similar to `__VA_ARGS__` but for a regular function, not macros. I don't mind taking this out of some symbol table etc. as long as it works.

To do something like this:

```
#define FUNC_ENTER printName(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__); printArgs(__WHAT_IM_MISSING__);

void someFunc(int a, int b)
{
    FUNC_ENTER;
    
    // ... rest of the function ...
}

void main()
{
    someFunc(5, 10);

    // Should print "Entering 'someFunc' with '5 10'" or something similar. 
}
```

P.S.1. I know I could make it work with writing `FUNC_ENTER(a, b)` - but I'd like to save myself typing the arguments

P.S.2. Don't suggest GCC's __cyg_profile_func_enter - as I don't want this macro for *every* function.

Comment: No it's not really possible to create something like this generically, unless you pass the actual arguments to the macro.

Comment: The problem is that preprocessor is processing text, not C code. Thus it is not aware that there exists something like function arguments. It does not even know that the macro expands within function body

Comment: However you could use xmacro to expand **both** to function parameters and a print command. Though the code may be a bit obfuscated

Comment: @tstanisl It doesn't necessary need to be macro. Any way to achieve this is fine. Also what is "xmacro" - when I google it nothing comes up (or it's overwhelmed by macro results)

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to get the pointer of the current function and use it to search symbols table (or some other things like they use in backtrace)  to get arguments?

Comment: C or C++? C++ has a few tricks that C does not. So distinction is important

Comment: The program is in C++.

Answer (score 3):

Note: the following is all specific to C++.

I don't know of a clean way of doing this *inside* the function in question. But you can pretty easily do it as a *wrapper* for the function, on this general order:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// just a couple functions with different number/types of arguments
// to demonstrate invoking
int someFunc(int a, int b) { 
    return a + b;
}

void otherFunc(std::string const &a, int b, long long c) { 
    std::cout << "a: " << a << ", b: " << b << ", c: " << c;
}

// Print out arguments, then invoke function:
template <class F, typename ...Args>
auto invoke(F f, Args && ...args) {
    (std::cout << "Args: " << ... << args) << "\n";
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() { 
    std::cout << invoke(someFunc, 1, 2) << "\n";
    invoke(otherFunc, "first", 2, 3);
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

If you want to "hide" the implementation from the user so they only have to call an ordinary looking function, you can pretty easily add a little wrapper for each individual function, something along this line:

```cpp
namespace {
// this is the actual implementation, hidden from the user
void function_implementation(/* whatever args*/) { 
    // ...
}
}

// this is all the user sees--print args, then invoke implementation.
// For each wrapper, you edit the name you want the user to see, and the 
// implementation it invokes.
template <typename ...Args>
void function(Args && ...args) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    invoke(function_implementation, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

As this code stands, it has one minor difficulty: it doesn't insert a delimiter between each argument as it's printing them out. If you need that, you can (for one possibility) expand the parameter pack recursively instead of using a fold expression:

```cpp
template <class T>
void print(T const &t) {
    std::cout << t << "\t";
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void print(T n, Args ... args) {
    print(n);
    print(args...);
    std::cout << "\n";
}

template <class F, typename ...Args>
auto invoke(F f, Args && ...args) {
    print(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, although it is unfortunately completely impractical. I intended to use it to trace function invocations. I cannot pollute the code with invoke() everywhere or write the wrapper for every function I want to trace. That's hundreds... I guess I'll explicitly pass arguments to my print then, like `FUNC_ENTER(a, b)`. Thanks nonetheless.